# IIR filter embedded implementation for PPG data

Tags: filter, scipy, digital

I am working on a project where I need to filter sensor acquired PPG data. Looking at several papers, the best rated filter for this use case is the Chebyshev II filter, which I would like to use as well.

My dataset consists of 600 18bit ADC values. The processing takes place after collecting current samples, and are filtered. After that, I apply the qppg algorithm for peak detection to calculate the heart rate variance.

Working on the implementation, I first started implementing it in Python and later I need to re-write it into C. In Scipy libraries, the recommended approach is computing the sos coefficients with `cheby2()` and applying it on the data with `sosfiltfilt()` funtion. This works quite well.

However, what I planned to do, was pre-computing the a, b coefficients of the transfer function, hardcoding them in the C source files and using a for-loop for application on signal data via direct form I or II (yes, I thought it would be this easy). Closely inspection the `filtfilt()` function I found out, it uses odd extension and then an underlying C implementation of `lfiter()` (`_linear_filter()`), which I cannot reproduce.

The problem with similar post on this forum is, that for correct result the `lfilter()` function requires the use of `zi` parameter which provides the initial conditions for filter delays and I do not know how could I apply them in the calculation.

My question is: Is it possible to achieve the filtering result in an easier and more concise way using the simplest operations possible (to be later re-written into embedded C)? If yes, how?

If not, what other approaches can I try? I kind of ran out of ideas and right now I am thinking of resorting to a simpler filtering algorithm (e.g. Butterworth).

Answer (score 0):

The IIR filter implementation is quite simple. I assume that the z1 parameter you talk about is Type I or II form memory ?

Taken from [this IIR implementation in gtkiostream][1] you should be able to port this C++ code to C :

```
// Direct Form II algorithm
for (int i=0; i<x.rows(); i++){
  mem.row(0)=-x.row(i);
  mem.row(0)=-(A*mem.block(0, 0, A.rows(), A.cols())).colwise().sum();
  yTemp.row(i)=(B*mem.block(0, 0, B.rows(), B.cols())).colwise().sum();
  for (int j=mem.rows()-1; j>0; j--)
    mem.row(j)=mem.row(j-1);
}
```

In the code, rows are time samples and columns are different IIR filters. A and B are the denominator and numerator coefficients respectively. mem is the memory, probably z1 which you talk about and must be stored between each iteration of the input signal to find the output signal.
[1]: https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/src/DSP/IIR.C#L83-L89